# Problem with pytorch and cuda installation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, anaconda

I am trying to install PyTorch with Cuda using Anaconda3, on Windows 11

My `nvidia-smi` outputs `Driver Version: 551.76, CUDA Version: 12.4`

My torch version is this which I intalled from official site for 12.2

```
torch 2.2.1+cu121
torchaudio 2.2.1+cu121
torchvision 0.17.1+cu121
```

But the problem is that when I run `torch.cuda.is_available()` it shows `false` as an output. What is wrong here?